# WPF - Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is sending me nuts, mostly because at runtime it works perfectly (the problem only appear at design time), but I decided to ask anyway as I'm working on a big project and I want to implement things the best way.

First thing: I have a component from a third part library, it is basically like a border, and it's defined this way (with F12):

```
public class AdvancedBorder : ContentControl
```

I like the visual aspect of this thing, but I need to add some functionalities. So I created a new Custom Control:

```
public class SelectableCard : AdvancedBorder
{
    // bunch of custom properties and stuff

    static SelectableCard()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SelectableCard), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SelectableCard)));
    }
}
```

Finally I need to keep the exactly same visual but adding some triggers, so I put this in generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type customControls:SelectableCard}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type otherLibrary:AdvancedBorder}}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="customControls:SelectableCard.IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MyLightBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

`customControls` is the xmlns for my namespace, `otherLibrary` is the xmlns for the third part library.

Everything works perfectly fine at runtime, and gives no errors at all. At design time I get no errors from the generic.xaml, but as soon as I put the SelectableCard in some xaml file, I get

> Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type
>   SelectableCard

And I don't get it at all, especially as it works at runtime. I can remove the `BasedOn` attribute and I get no more complaints at design time, but then I have to add the setter for the template otherwise I can't see anything at runtime.

What am I doing wrong, here?

Comment: I've never bothered with that mostly, but did you try to put the namespace reference in the external xaml file? Does that change anything?

Comment: As a rule it's a mistake to blame anything on bugs in Visual Studio, but there's an exception to everything, and the XAML designer is a little funny sometimes. Usually harmlessly so.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I never assume is a VStudio fault, unless I'm working with the WPF designer :-D  But even in that case, 99% of the time I can find a way to fix the problem and discover that it was my fault anyway. In this case, I already know that if I remove the BasedOn and add the setter for the Template property everything will work fine, and that's the reason I'm trying to understand if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: As you see, the code compiles and runs fine. I agree with the comment from @Ed, this is one of those unfortunate cases where the XAML editor is just plain wrong. Note that the editor isn't actually running the XAML compiler to generate these kinds of messages; it effectively has it's own copy of a XAML compiler built-in, and that compiler isn't entirely bug-free (when, oh when!, will we get the equivalent of Roslyn for the XAML compiler...sigh).

Comment: In my experience, sometimes you can change the declarations so that they still work like you want, but the XAML editor doesn't complain (but I don't have a specific suggestion in this example). In other cases, you just have to grin and bear it. :(